width:100% is not considered when working with nested grid in CSS in print mode
I'm generating A4 invoice using HTML, CSS and JS. This looks fine in normal mode but the width goes beyond 100% and horizontal scroll bar starts to appear in print preview.
Here is my code snippet:
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #section-to-print {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Calibri, monospace;
            font-size: 0.8rem;
            margin: 1rem;
            border: 1px solid;
        }

        body ol {
            list-style: none;
            padding-left: 0;
            margin: 0.5rem 0;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            page-break-inside: auto;
        }

        td section div {
            page-break-inside: avoid;
        }

        thead {
            display: table-header-group;
        }

        tfoot {
            display: table-footer-group;
        }

        header {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 0 0.5rem;
            position: relative;
        }

        header h1 {
            font-size: 2rem;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 0;
        }

        header h2 {
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 0;
        }

        header h3 {
            font-size: 1rem;
            font-weight: normal;
            margin: 0;
        }

        header ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding-left: 0;
            margin: 0.5rem 0;
        }

        header #brand {
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
            padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            width: 100%;
        }

        header #phone {
            position: absolute;
            text-align: right;
            top: 0;
            right: 0.5rem;
        }

        header #invoicedetails {
            display: grid;
            grid: "customer-billed customer-shipped invoice";
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            padding: 0 0.5rem;
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
            width: 100%;
        }

        header #customer-billed {
            text-align: left;
        }

        header #customer-shipped {
            border: 1px solid;
            border-top: 0;
            border-bottom: 0;
            padding-left: 0.5rem;
            text-align: left;
        }

        header #invoice {
            text-align: right;
        }

        table tbody td {
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        main {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #invoiceitems {
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        #itemscontent {
            height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            /*Below line is added as inline style in A4 invoice component*/
            /*grid: "sno description hsn scale scale2 unit price unitprice";*/
            /*grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(1rem, max-content)) auto repeat(2, minmax(1rem, max-content));*/
            /*grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, max-content) minmax(min-content, auto) max-content max-content max-content max-content max-content max-content;*/
            grid-auto-rows: minmax(1rem, max-content);
            grid-column-gap: 1px;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #itemscontent>div {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            border: 1px solid;
            height: 100%;
            border-top: 0;
            border-right: 0;
            padding: 0 0.25rem;
        }

        .border-left-0 {
            border-left: 0 !important;
        }

        .border-bottom-0 {
            border-bottom: 0 !important;
        }

        .border-top-1 {
            border-top: 1px solid black !important;
        }

        .span-2 {
            grid-column-start: span 2;
        }

        .span-3 {
            grid-column-start: span 3;
        }

        .span-4 {
            grid-column-start: span 4;
        }

        .span-5 {
            grid-column-start: span 5;
        }

        .span-7 {
            grid-column-start: span 7;
        }

        .text-darkgreen {
            color: darkgreen;
        }

        .text-red {
            color: red;
        }

        .bg-yellow {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        .flex-end {
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }

        footer {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        #itemsfooter {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            border-left: 0 !important;
        }

        #itemsfooter>div {
            align-self: stretch;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 0 0.5rem;
        }

        #amountinwords {
            flex: 75%;
        }

        #totalamount {
            flex: 25%;
            text-align: right;
            border-left: 1px solid black;
        }

        #totalamount ol {
            width: 100%;
        }

        #totalamount ol li:last-child {
            font-size: x-large;
        }

        #invoiceinformation {
            text-transform: none;
            border-left: 0 !important;
            display: grid !important;
            grid: "note" "bankdetails" "signature";
            grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, 40%) minmax(min-content, 35%) minmax(min-content, 25%);
            padding: 0 0.5rem;
        }

        #invoiceinformation div {
            align-self: stretch;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 0 0.5rem;
        }

        /* #note {
            flex: 40%;
        } */

        #bankdetails {
            /* flex: 35%; */
            border: 1px solid;
            border-top: 0;
            border-bottom: 0;
        }

        #signature {
            display: flex;
            /* flex: 25%; */
            border-left: 0 !important;
            padding-right: 0.5rem !important;
        }

        #message {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            border-left: 0 !important;
            border-bottom: 0 !important;
            padding: 0 0.5rem !important;
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media print {
            @page {
                size: A4;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <header>
                        <section id="brand">
                            <h1>BRAND</h1>
                            <h2>CAPTION</h2>
                            <h3>TAG LINE</h3>
                            <div>Address</div>
                            <div><b>TAX Invoice</b></div>
                            <section id="phone">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Phone: </li>
                                    <li></li>
                                </ul>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                        <section id="invoicedetails">
                            <section id="customer-billed">
                                <ol>
                                    <li>Billed To</li>
                                    <li><b>ABC </b></li>
                                    <li>Mobile: </li>
                                    <li>Address: </li>
                                </ol>
                            </section>
                            <section id="customer-shipped">
                                <ol>
                                    <li>Shipped To</li>
                                    <li><b>ABC </b></li>
                                    <li>Mobile: </li>
                                    <li>Address: </li>
                                </ol>
                            </section>
                            <section id="invoice">
                                <ol>
                                    <li>Invoice Details</li>
                                    <li>Invoice No: <b>2/2024-25</b></li>
                                    <li>DC No: <b>2102</b></li>
                                    <li>Invoice Date: <b>01 Apr 2024</b></li>
                                    <li>Payment Mode: <b>Credit</b></li>
                                    <li>Payment Status: <b>Due</b></li>
                                </ol>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </header>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <main style="padding-bottom: 0">
                        <section id="invoiceitems">
                            <section id="itemscontent"
                                style="grid: 'sno description hsn scale  price unit unitprice'; grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, max-content) minmax(min-content, auto) max-content max-content  max-content max-content max-content; grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(1rem, max-content));">

                                <div class="border-left-0">S.No</div>

                                <div>Description</div>
                                <div><b></b></div>
                                <div>Days</div>
                                <div>Unit</div>

                                <div>Price</div>

                                <div>Unit Price</div>
                                <div id="invoiceinformation" class="span-7">
                                    <div id="note">
                                        <small>NOTE</small>
                                        <br>
                                        <text>Certified that the particulars
                                            given above are true and correct</text>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="bankdetails">
                                        <small>COMPANY BANK DETAILS</small>
                                        <br>
                                        <text>BANK:
                                            ABC BANK, A/C. NO: 1111111111111111, IFSC: IABC0000000, Branch: DEF
                                            Road, GHI</text>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="signature">
                                        <text><b>for ABC</b>
                                            <br>
                                            <br>
                                            <br>Authorized Signatory</text>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </main>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>

In normal mode:
All looks good.

In Print Preview or when Printed:
Horizontal scroll bar appears in print. I'm checking this by setting Emulate CSS media type to print.

This breaks the layout when I print to PDF

However I noticed a strange behavior when I remove the content inside my nested grid #invoiceinformation. I commented the <text> node inside #note and #bankdetails and then horizontal scroll bar disappeared.
Emulate CSS media type to Print after commenting <text> node:

Print to PDF after commenting <text> node.

The above output is the expected one even when I have data inside <text> node. So I tried to set width:100% to #invoiceinformation grid but its not working.
Please assist me on what I'm missing?

It’s this grid definition which is causing the problem.
<section id="itemscontent" style="grid: sno description hsn scale price unit unitprice; grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, max-content) minmax(min-content, auto) max-content max-content  max-content max-content max-content; grid-template-rows: repeat(5, minmax(1rem, max-content)) auto repeat(3, minmax(1rem, max-content));">

Reset it so that all widths and heights are auto, then just tweak from there using percentages or fractions.


#section-to-print {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Calibri, monospace;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid;
}

body ol {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    page-break-inside: auto;
}

td section div {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}

thead {
    display: table-header-group;
}

tfoot {
    display: table-footer-group;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

header h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

header h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

header ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

header #brand {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}

header #phone {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
    right: 0.5rem;
}

header #invoicedetails {
    display: grid;
    grid: "customer-billed customer-shipped invoice";
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
}

header #customer-billed {
    text-align: left;
}

header #customer-shipped {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    text-align: left;
}

header #invoice {
    text-align: right;
}

table tbody td {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

#invoiceitems {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#itemscontent {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    /*Below line is added as inline style in A4 invoice component*/
    /*grid: "sno description hsn scale scale2 unit price unitprice";*/
    /*grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(1rem, max-content)) auto repeat(2, minmax(1rem, max-content));*/
    /*grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, max-content) minmax(min-content, auto) max-content max-content max-content max-content max-content max-content;*/
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(1rem, max-content);
    grid-column-gap: 1px;
    align-items: center;
}

#itemscontent>div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    padding: 0 0.25rem;
}

.border-left-0 {
    border-left: 0 !important;
}

.border-bottom-0 {
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.border-top-1 {
    border-top: 1px solid black !important;
}

.span-2 {
    grid-column-start: span 2;
}

.span-3 {
    grid-column-start: span 3;
}

.span-4 {
    grid-column-start: span 4;
}

.span-5 {
    grid-column-start: span 5;
}

.span-7 {
    grid-column-start: span 7;
}

.text-darkgreen {
    color: darkgreen;
}

.text-red {
    color: red;
}

.bg-yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.flex-end {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#itemsfooter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-left: 0 !important;
}

#itemsfooter>div {
    align-self: stretch;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

#amountinwords {
    flex: 75%;
}

#totalamount {
    flex: 25%;
    text-align: right;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

#totalamount ol {
    width: 100%;
}

#totalamount ol li:last-child {
    font-size: x-large;
}

#invoiceinformation {
    text-transform: none;
    border-left: 0 !important;
    display: grid !important;
    grid: "note" "bankdetails" "signature";
    grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, 40%) minmax(min-content, 35%) minmax(min-content, 25%);
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

#invoiceinformation div {
    align-self: stretch;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

/* #note {
    flex: 40%;
} */

#bankdetails {
    /* flex: 35%; */
    border: 1px solid;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

#signature {
    display: flex;
    /* flex: 25%; */
    border-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0.5rem !important;
}

#message {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-left: 0 !important;
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 0.5rem !important;
}

@media print {
    @page {
        size: A4;
    }
}
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <header>
                        <section id="brand">
                            <h1>BRAND</h1>
                            <h2>CAPTION</h2>
                            <h3>TAG LINE</h3>
                            <div>Address</div>
                            <div><b>TAX Invoice</b></div>
                            <section id="phone">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Phone: </li>
                                    <li></li>
                                </ul>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                        <section id="invoicedetails">
                            <section id="customer-billed">
                                <ol>
                                    <li>Billed To</li>
                                    <li><b>ABC </b></li>
                                    <li>Mobile: </li>
                                    <li>Address: </li>
                                </ol>
                            </section>
                            <section id="customer-shipped">
                                <ol>
                                    <li>Shipped To</li>
                                    <li><b>ABC </b></li>
                                    <li>Mobile: </li>
                                    <li>Address: </li>
                                </ol>
                            </section>
                            <section id="invoice">
                                <ol>
                                    <li>Invoice Details</li>
                                    <li>Invoice No: <b>2/2024-25</b></li>
                                    <li>DC No: <b>2102</b></li>
                                    <li>Invoice Date: <b>01 Apr 2024</b></li>
                                    <li>Payment Mode: <b>Credit</b></li>
                                    <li>Payment Status: <b>Due</b></li>
                                </ol>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </header>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <main style="padding-bottom: 0">
                        <section id="invoiceitems">
                            <section id="itemscontent"
                                style="grid: sno description hsn scale  price unit unitprice; grid-template-columns: repeat(7, auto); grid-template-rows: repeat(9, auto)">

                                <div class="border-left-0">S.No</div>

                                <div>Description</div>
                                <div><b></b></div>
                                <div>Days</div>
                                <div>Unit</div>

                                <div>Price</div>

                                <div>Unit Price</div>
                                <div id="invoiceinformation" class="span-7">
                                    <div id="note">
                                        <small>NOTE</small>
                                        <br>
                                        <text>Certified that the particulars
                                            given above are true and correct</text>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="bankdetails">
                                        <small>COMPANY BANK DETAILS</small>
                                        <br>
                                        <text>BANK:
                                            ABC BANK, A/C. NO: 1111111111111111, IFSC: IABC0000000, Branch: DEF
                                            Road, GHI</text>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="signature">
                                        <text><b>for ABC</b>
                                            <br>
                                            <br>
                                            <br>Authorized Signatory</text>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </main>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>



PS. I advise you to use a grid instead of a table for the overall layout as well.

Lemme check and get back... The reason behind using table is that when the content goes beyond more than one page, table header nicely adds thead in all pages

I need the grid to have two rows exactly. In that case grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(1rem, max-content)); should work right? Is it mandatory to set it to auto?

I corrected the style:grid in #itemscontent in a way that it looks like this 7 columns and 2 rows. both with grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows and now I'm noticing that if I remove grid-template-columns the grid fits exactly
